# How to bind data with combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, combobox

I need to know in the simplest form, how to bind **data (list of string)** to **a ComboBox** in **XAML** without using **ComboBox.ItemSource = object** in the **code behind**.

I mean what is this:

```
{Binding Path="What Comes here"}
```

let's say I have:

```
class Window1 : UserControl {

     List<String> list = new List<String>();// And assign Value to this list
...}
```

I've tried

```
{Binding Path=list} or {Binding list}
```

but nothing has been bind. So how should it be done? (I can't access this combobox in the code behind because **Microsoft has limited SilverLight DatGrid to an extent** that I can't do it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Few rules for binding to work properly:

1. You can bind only with **public properties** *(at least for instance objects)* and not with fields.
2. Be default binding engine looks for property path in **DataContext** of control where binding is applied on.
3. If you want to bind to property which doesn't exist in DataContext *(or DataContext is not set for control)*, use **RelativeSource** markup extension to guide binding engine to resolve property path.

---

Coming back to your problem statement where you need to bind to List created in code behind, you have to do following changes to code:

```
// Not sure why you termed it as Window1 if it's actually an UserControl.
public partial class Window1 : UserControl
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyStrings = new List<string>(new[] { "A", "B", "C", "D" });
        DataContext = this; // Rule #2
    }

    public List<string> MyStrings { get; set; } // Rule #1
}
```

*XAML*:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings}"/>
```

---

In case you don't set DataContext in constructor of UserControl and still want to bind to property, bind using RelativeSource *(Rule #3)*

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyStrings, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor
                                       , AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

---

**Additional Points**

1. Use `ObservableCollection<string>` in place of `List<string>` in case you want to add more items to the list after initialization and want UI to update accordingly.
2. Read more about MVVM here - [**Understanding the basics of MVVM pattern**](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msgulfcommunity/archive/2013/03/13/understanding_2d00_the_2d00_basics_2d00_of_2d00_mvvm_2d00_design_2d00_pattern.aspx). Generally all binding stuff stay in separate class ViewModel so that it can be tested w/o any dependency on UI stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look over here: [Model-View-ViewModel (MVVM) Explained](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)

I'm not a SilverLight developer but as far as I know it's just a downstiped version of full wpf.

Try using a ViewModel and define your list in there. Then you can bind the `ComboBox.ItemsSource` property to it:

```
public class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> listOfAwesomeStrings;

    public ObservableCollection<string> ListOfAwesomeStrings
    {
        get { return listOfAwesomeStrings; }
        set
        {
            if (value.Equals(listOfAwesomeStrings))
            {
                return;
            }

            listOfAwesomeStrings= value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;

        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

---

Set the `DataContext` of your view like this and also fill your list:

```
var viewModel = new SomeViewModel();

viewModel.ListOfAwesomeStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
viewModel.ListOfAwesomeStrings.Add("Option 1");
viewModel.ListOfAwesomeStrings.Add("Option 2");
viewModel.ListOfAwesomeStrings.Add("Option 3");

this.DataContext = viewModel;
```

---

Finally bind to your property in xaml:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfAwesomeStrings}" />
```